# Update large number of rows - SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have several tab-separated files which I would like to use to update a large number of rows. So far I have naively created a temp table and imported the data into it and then updated the table which also involved a join. This created a large trans log. I would like to prevent this and do it in chunks. I have found this:

http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/itanswers/bulk-update-in-sql-server-2005/

Is this the best way?

Are there even faster methods (SSIS, bcp)?

Any feedback highly appreciated. Thanks.

Christian

PS:

My naive code looks like this. Unfort. i is not a primary key (the table has one as Bla is a child of another table)

```
drop table #temp
create table #temp
(
    i int,
    xml nvarchar(max)
)
BULK INSERT #temp 
...

update a
set XML = b.xml
from Bla as a
inner join #temp as b on a.i = b.i
```

Comment: Does your table have a primary key? Or is there some other indexes in place that would allow the next batch to easily start where the last one finished? In fact what is the structure of the tables involved and the update statement?

Comment: I can't really see any obvious way of improving upon the technique in your link based on that structure,

Comment: Thanks Martin. Does this 'TOP technique' commit the transaction automatically and thus prevents the transaction log to grow. I don't see any explicit transaction stuff ... thanks.

Comment: Yes. So long as you don't open an explicit transaction yourself and aren't running in `implicit transaction` mode (which is not the default) then it will commit automatically.

Comment: would you like to write an asnswer so I can accept it? otherwise I will delete this ...

Comment: I'd leave this open for a bit. There might be some other approach that I'm not aware of.

Comment: @martin this seems to be the only way. so please feel free to post an answer. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have an indexed identity column in the target table? This is one of the few cases where I actually like to use a WHILE loop. The main problem with the solution in the link you posted is bad index usage.

```
    DECLARE @START INT, @FINISH INT, @LOOPEND INT
    SELECT @START = 1, @FINISH = 5000, @LOOPEND = MAX(ID)
    from Bla 

    WHILE @START <= @LOOPEND
    BEGIN
        update a
        set XML = b.xml
        from Bla as a
        inner join #temp as b on a.i = b.i
        WHERE a.ID BETWEEN @START AND @FINISH

        SET @START = @FINISH + 1
        SET @FINISH = @FINISH + 5000
    END
```

In cases where you have a surrogate key (identity column as primary key), which is not so uncommon, this would cause a simple index seek on the primary key and is adjustable simply by the growth amount (5000 in the example)

Comment: My situation is that the target table 'a' has its own primary key. The column 'i' is indexed but is no primary key (I used the query optimiser). I have tried a 'looping solution' like yours but did it row by row. i like your approach and will try it tonight. thanks.