# Copy data from one column to another in oracle table

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, relational-database

My current project for a client requires me to work with Oracle databases (11g). Most of my previous database experience is with MSSQL Server, Access, and MySQL. I've recently run into an issue that seems incredibly strange to me and I was hoping someone could provide some clarity.

I was looking to do a statement like the following:

```
update MYTABLE set COLUMN_A = COLUMN_B;
```

MYTABLE has about 13 million rows.

The source column is indexed (COLUMN_B), but the destination column is not (COLUMN_A)

The primary key field is a GUID.

This seems to run for 4 hours but never seems to complete.

I spoke with a former developer that was more familiar with Oracle than I, and they told me you would normally create a procedure that breaks this down into chunks of data to be commited (roughly 1000 records or so). This procedure would iterate over the 13 million records and commit 1000 records, then commit the next 1000...normally breaking the data up based on the primary key.

This sounds somewhat silly to me coming from my experience with other database systems. I'm not joining another table, or linking to another database. I'm simply copying data from one column to another. I don't consider 13 million records to be large considering there are systems out there in the orders of billions of records. I can't imagine it takes a computer hours and hours (only to fail) at copying a simple column of data in a table that as a whole takes up less than 1 GB of storage.

In experimenting with alternative ways of accomplishing what I want, I tried the following:

```
create table MYTABLE_2 as (SELECT COLUMN_B, COLUMN_B as COLUMN_A from MYTABLE);
```

This took less than 2 minutes to accomplish the exact same end result (minus dropping the first table and renaming the new table).

Why does the UPDATE run for 4 hours and fail (which simply copies one column into another column), but the create table which copies the entire table takes less than 2 minutes?

And are there any best practices or common approaches used to do this sort of change? Thanks for your help!

Comment: The problem is the logging of the changes.  It is problem in other databases too, including the ones you mention (for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344984/update-large-number-of-rows-sql-server-2005).  Perhaps this will help you as well:  http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_efficient_update_sql_dml_tips.htm.

Comment: Are there any triggers on the table?  Does the `UPDATE` statement substantially increase the size of rows in the table?  If so, a large amount of the time could be spent migrating rows.  Are there any foreign keys that reference `column_a`?  What is the query plan?  Have you traced the session to see where the time is being spent?

Comment: The provided example is essentially the real table. There are no rows added (just copying one column to another in the same table). There are no foreign keys. Just the query shown. I am unable to trace the session currently because I'm awaiting responses from DBAs in Germany to provide me with access or to assist me in optimizing things further -- I have limited permissions (the client's internal DBAs are either very busy or not interested in assisting :D). That's why I'm trying to gain what knowledge I can so when I do interact with the client DBAs I'm not completely in the dark.

Comment: @gordon - Thanks for the info. I'll do some more reading into them. I'm definitely more of a developer than a database guy. The problem I find is most "database guys" I talk to are either also developers and use the database as a glorified data store (no stored procedures or utilization of relational DB features), or they go into unix mode of read the manual. :) I don't have time on this project to attend Oracle training so as I come across problems I read what I can to meet the customers needs and move on. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does seem strange to me.  However, this comes to mind:

When you are updating the table, transaction logs must be created in case a rollback is needed.  Creating a table, that isn't necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I was contemplating about transactional information required due to concern over other queries which could occur in parallel that touch this table. But I'm still baffled by the difference in performance. I wonder if I could force some kind of lock on the table and see if it streamlines the process.

Comment: Here is an interesting (but very old) Ask Tom answer to a similar question: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6407993912330    Basically, "If I had to update millions of records I would probably opt to NOT update."  Create a new table then add indexes, constraints, etc.

Comment: This is incredibly silly, but it seems it is the best approach. Thanks for the find. I'd love to see the internals of how this is working under the hood because I can't imagine they made Update be a useless statement. Oracle apparently takes the U out of CRUD. CRD it is ;)